# Update props in instance of an vue component for unittest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js

I am about to test some behaviour in a Vue component which only occurs on props change.
The Vue component looks similar to this component, the relevant logic for the test happens in the watcher.

```
<script>
export default {
  components: {
  },
  props: {
    examleProp: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: false,
      default: false,
    }
  },
  watch: {
    exampleProp: function(newVal, oldVal) {
        // logic which needs to be tested
    },
  }
};
</script>

<template>
  <h1>hello world</h1>
</template>
```

The test logic is running fine when following the below approach.

```
it('example test', done => {
    let wrapper = mount(exampleComponent, {
        propsData: {
        },
        template: `
        <example-component >
        </example-component>
    `
    });

    wrapper.setProps({
        isSubmitting: true
    });
});
```

The watcher is called and ready to be tested, all good.

Since the test is supposed to be integrated in a testsuite, there are some limitations.
The component is not mounted but the instance of it like this:

```
it('example test', done => {
     let wrapper = new Vue({
      components: {
        exampleComponent,
      },
      template: `
        <example-component></example-component>
      `,
    }).$mount();

    // how to update props now?
    // wrapper.setProps  && wrapper.$setProps are both undefined
});
```

So what i am trying to achieve is a way to update the props of the instance of an component to trigger the watcher to run, any Ideas on this?

Comment: this might help https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/unit-testing.html#Writing-Testable-Components

Comment: not really :( it shows how to set up props initally und how to update component data, but how to update props dynamically seems to be missing.

Comment: Can you clarify why you need to instantiate the Vue instance for your test suite? Why can't `mount()/shallowMount()` be used in that case?

Comment: Where are you passing any props to `example-component`?

Comment: @ConstantinGroß in both examples using the setProps method, to be precise it's the comment in the second example

Comment: Why not `<example-component :isSubmitting="true">` in the test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you absolutely must use an actual Vue instance in the test-suite instead of the test-utils wrapper, you can do this:

1. Update the prop by making it dependent on an arbitrary data property of the Vue instance itself (i.e., `vm.unchanged`).
2. Insert a `vm.$set` call into the `vm.mounted()` lifecycle hook that changes `vm.unchanged`, thus triggering the `watch` on `exampleComponent.exampleProp`.

```js
const exampleComponent = {
  components: {
  },
  template: `<div>
<h1 style="color: green">ExamleProp unchanged: {{ exampleProp }}</h1>
<h1 style="color: red">Updated: {{ updated }}</h1>
</div>`,
  props: {
    exampleProp: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: false,
      default: false,
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      updated: false,
    };
  },
  watch: {
    exampleProp: function(newVal, oldVal) {
        this.updated = true;
    },
  }
};

const vm = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      components: {
        exampleComponent,
      },
      data: {
        unchanged: true,
      },
      template: `
        <example-component :example-prop="unchanged"></example-component>
      `,
      mounted() {
        this.$set(this, 'unchanged', false);
      } 
    }).$mount();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Hope that helps!